# PHP Execute if URL has prefix

Tags: php

I have multiple pages with the `magic` prefix, the URL is like so for the main page:

> dashboard.php?page=magic

and for the other subpages like so:

> dashboard.php?page=magic_dothisandthat

but that way I have to add them all to my stylesheet execution script;

```
if(isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == 'magic') {
     '<link rel="stylesheet" href="example">';
}
```

Is there a way to execute the stylesheet HTML on all pages which have the `magic_` prefix?

Example what I mean:

```
if($_GET['page'] == 'magic_' *) {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if the first 5 characters of `$page` equal magic:

```
if(isset($_GET['page']) && substr($_GET['page'],0,5) == 'magic') {
     '<link rel="stylesheet" href="example">';
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Answer (score 2):

Use strpos to see if it's the the `magic_` prefix is at the first index.

```
if (strpos($_GET['page'], 'magic_') === 0) {
  echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="example">';
}
```

Comment: that works, but is there a way to also include the main page `magic` in there so it also executes on the main page?

Comment: Ideally the code should be structured that this all goes through a common point. But if it isn't structured that way, you should factor this out into a common file where you keep your common functions or just make it a file on its own and use `require 'magic_stylesheet.php';`

Comment: wish I could accept both answers but the answer of almo worked 100% for me so I have to accept that one in this case, thank you for your effort to help me out, it is gladly appriciated